# Permission denied causing "Installation failed due to invalid APK file"

Tags: java, android, adb

When I try to run my app on my Nexus 4 running 4.2.1, I kept on getting this error in eclipse:

```
[2012-12-22 19:30:51 - Rhiokai] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2012-12-22 19:30:51 - Rhiokai] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-12-22 19:30:51 - Rhiokai] Launch canceled!
```

I tired pushing and installing via adb but it didn't work either. I figured out that it was because of this message in Logcat:

```
12-22 19:37:29.326: W/zipro(7371): Unable to open zip '/data/local/tmp/Rhiokai.apk': Permission denied
12-22 19:37:29.326: D/asset(7371): failed to open Zip archive '/data/local/tmp/Rhiokai.apk'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Perhaps your folder is lacking the appropriate permissions?

Answer (score 21):

I started receiving this error after rooting my phone.

The reason for "permission denied" is that apk files uploaded to /data/local/tmp had the -rw----- permission and owned by root, and the installer process obviously did not have permissions to read any such file.

I never found a solution, but have a workaround that satisfies me. I have simply moved/symlinked the tmp directory to the SD card. Since SD card is formatted as FAT, it does not have owners/permissions and all files created there are always readable by everyone.

```
# cd /data/local
# mv tmp tmp-old # (or simply rm -rf tmp)
# mkdir /mnt/sdcard/tmp
# ln -s /mnt/sdcard/tmp ./tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly, the age old trick of turning the phone off and back on again worked