# Galaxy S3 app debugging: unable to open zip archive. Permission denied

Tags: android, eclipse

USB debugging is enabled, installing non-market apps is enabled, and my device is recognized properly in Eclipse. But when I try to run my app with my phone connected, I get:

```
[2012-12-26 19:07:38 - TestApp] Installing TestApp.apk...
[2012-12-26 19:07:39 - TestApp] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2012-12-26 19:07:39 - TestApp] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-12-26 19:07:39 - TestApp] Launch canceled!
```

LogCat shows this:

```
Unable to open Zip archive 'data/local/tmp/TestApp.apk': Permission Denied
failed to open Zip archive 'data/local/tmp/TestApp.apk'
```

I googled for a while and couldn't find anything that worked as a solution, but I just don't know what's going on. Someone said to start an adb shell and use chmod 777 /data. Tried that for the hell of it, but it was no use. Someone else said it might be a custom ROM issue, so I reverted to rooted stock and it's still giving me the same problems. I've also tried cleaning the project with Eclipse, rebooting everything and deleting my .android folder. I'm completely at a loss.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

EDIT: The app also installs just fine if I email it to myself and install it through the gmail app.

Comment: have you tried removing the USB cable from your PC before running the app?

Comment: I haven't, but since the app is going to be debugged over the USB cable, I don't see how that would help my issue. I should add that the APK installs fine if I email it to myself.

Comment: the thing is sometimes the SD card gets mounted over USB and becomes unavailable to the apps running on the device. I had this issue once writing a file to SD card and removing the cable resolved it.

Also, did you add a permission for accessing the SD card to the manifest?

Comment: What exactly does the app do? Perhaps there is some check in the OS level that is denying the app installation permissison because its accessing a system level permission.. perhaps.

Comment: The only permissions I've added to the manifest are fine, coarse and mock location data. 

@Androidz, I see what you're saying now. I only have my internal storage. There's no external storage right now. The only issue with unplugging is that I can't debug and figure out why my app is crashing. But when I plug it in, I notice now that the internal storage is mounted for file transfer. Can I disable that mounting but still have it plugged in for debugging?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14890187/1155151

This answer solved the same issue for me on my Galaxy S3

If you have rooted your phone then there can be an issue where the data/local/tmp directory has  -rw----- permission and is owned by root and the installer process has insufficient permissions. Creating a symlink bypasses this problem as permissions on this folder appear to be overridden at some point.

```
# cd /data/local
# mv tmp tmp-old # (or simply rm -rf tmp)
# mkdir /mnt/sdcard/tmp
# ln -s /mnt/sdcard/tmp ./tmp
```