# Android - Installation failed due to invalid APK file after Root

Tags: android, debugging, root, logcat

I get this error on USB Debugging after root:

```
Installation failed due to invalid APK file! Please check logcat
output for more details. [2013-11-10 09:48:35 - xxxxxxx] Launch
canceled!
```

I rooted with speedmod-kernel-s2-jb-k5-7-Odin. It worked fine before I rooted the device. But now it does not work anymore. I have already uninstalled the app. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Go here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014871/permission-denied-causing-installation-failed-due-to-invalid-apk-file

Comment: That does not work. I tried it but no changes.