# Android Studio doesn't have the permission to install apk copied on /data/local/tmp

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, usb-debugging

While running my android application on my device Android Studio shows the device with its name properly and while selecting the device to run it gives the error:-

`Installing com.example.android.borderlessbuttons
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.android.borderlessbuttons"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.borderlessbuttons
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]`

and now the device name changed to `???????` implying permission denied or not identified. Again after doing,

`adb kill-server
 sudo adb start-server
 adb devices`

the device is listed again now.

I believe the problem is in my custom ROM. My custom ROM for some reason changed the permission for the directory `/data/local/tmp`. The apk is copied but not able to run/install on device.

So does anybody knows the default permission for this directory to copy and install/run applications from Android Studio??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014871/permission-denied-causing-installation-failed-due-to-invalid-apk-file/14890187#14890187) did the magic. The problem was of course the permission for `/data/local/tmp` directory.