# Is there a way to change the default directory to copy build apk from android studio to my device?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, file-permissions

By default Studio copy and installs from the directory `/data/local/tmp` on my device. And for some reason my custom ROM doesn't give enough permission to Studio to install from that location. So is it possible to copy and install the build apk from other location like sdcard? Or to give enough permission to Android Studio to install from `/data/local/tmp`

Comment: I believe that Android Studio just runs the adb `install` command, so if your custom ROM is doing the wrong thing with that, it's probably a problem with your ROM.

Comment: off course that's my ROM's problem. And I asked about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722650/android-studio-doesnt-have-the-permission-to-install-apk-copied-on-data-local) with no luck. That's why I asked this question. Anyhow I found a workaround and it can be seen in the above link. Thanks for the reply